# How do you use intent parameters in your fulfillment in Dialogflow?

Tags: javascript, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am new to Dialogflow and not overly experienced in Javascript so sorry if the question sounds basic! I have been trying to build a calculator to find the area of a circle using a radius that the user specifies, however, I am struggling to use the parameter that holds the radius in my fulfillment to use in my calculation. Whenever I look at the fulfillment response I see the following error:

```
{
  "error": "conv.parameters is not a function"
}
```

I would really appreciate any suggested changes to my code that can help me to get this working. Thanks!

My fulfillment code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');

const WELCOME_INTENT = 'Default Welcome Intent';
const FALLBACK_INTENT = 'Default Fallback Intent';
const CIRCLE_AREA_RADIUS_INTENT = 'CircleAreaRadius';
const UNIT_LENGTH_RADIUS = 'unit-length';

const app = dialogflow();

app.intent(WELCOME_INTENT, (conv) => {
    conv.ask("Welcome to Circle Calculator! What can I help you with?");
});

app.intent(FALLBACK_INTENT, (conv) => {
    conv.ask("Sorry, I didn't understand. What would you like me to do?");
});

app.intent(CIRCLE_AREA_RADIUS_INTENT, (conv) => {
    const radius = conv.parameters(UNIT_LENGTH_RADIUS);
    var area = Math.pow(radius, 2) * Math.PI;
    conv.ask(`The area of the circle is ${area}.`);
});

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intent parameters are a second argument that can be in your function:

```
app.intent(CIRCLE_AREA_RADIUS_INTENT, (conv, {unit-length} ) => {
    const radius = params[UNIT_LENGTH_RADIUS]
    const area = Math.pow(radius, 2) * Math.PI
    conv.ask(`The area of the circle is ${area}.`)
})
```

You can also make this simpler with object destructing. If you rename your parameter to *radius* in Dialogflow:

```
app.intent(CIRCLE_AREA_RADIUS_INTENT, (conv, {radius}) => {
    const area = Math.pow(radius, 2) * Math.PI
    conv.ask(`The area of the circle is ${area}.`)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Nick's answer is spot-on but I want to add one more point.

If your parameter's name in Dialogflow is UNIT_LENGTH_RADIUS, then you can access it in your code with:

```
const radius = conv.parameters['UNIT_LENGTH_RADIUS'];
```

by using brackets instead of parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for that extra info!

Answer (score 0):

The fulfillment inline editor in Dialogflow had issues with the code above for me, using the API v2.

I had to put the intent in single quotes:

```
app.intent('CIRCLE_AREA_RADIUS_INTENT', (conv, {radius}) => {
    const area = Math.pow(radius, 2) * Math.PI
    conv.ask(`The area of the circle is ${area}.`)
})
```